# обработчики, нужно сделать кнопку с событием

Tags: javascript

На кнопку повесить обработчик, который будет по клику удалять классы с блока с результатом по очереди в таком порядке:

six -> two -> three -> four -> one -> five

После того, как блок окажется пустым, добавить их в порядке возрастания:

one -> two -> three -> … -> six   правильно ли я сделал?

```js
 
           
 function clickClass() {
let resultPanel = document.getElementById("clickResult");
if (resultPanel.classList.contains("down")) {
    switch (resultPanel.classList.length) {
        case 7:
            resultPanel.classList.remove("six");
            break;
        case 6:
            resultPanel.classList.remove("two");
            break;
        case 5:
            resultPanel.classList.remove("three");
            break;
        case 4:
            resultPanel.classList.remove("four");
            break;
        case 3:
            resultPanel.classList.remove("one");
            break;
        case 2:
            resultPanel.classList.remove("five");
            resultPanel.classList.replace("down", "up");
            break;
    }
}
else if (resultPanel.classList.contains("up")) {
    switch (resultPanel.classList.length) {
        case 1:
            resultPanel.classList.add("one");
            break;
        case 2:
            resultPanel.classList.add("two");
            break;
        case 3:
            resultPanel.classList.add("three");
            break;
        case 4:
            resultPanel.classList.add("four");
            break;
        case 5:
            resultPanel.classList.add("five");
            break;
        case 6:
            resultPanel.classList.add("six");
            resultPanel.classList.replace("up", "down");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

```css
.one {
  font-size: 22px;
}
 
.two {
  font-weight: bold;
}
 
.three {
  font-style: italic;
}
 
.four {
  text-align: right;
}
 
.five {
  font-style: oblique;
}
 
.six {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="clickWrapper">
 
        <button class="clickButton" onclick="clickClass()">Click button</button>
        <div id="clickResult" class="one two three four five six down">one two three four five six</div>
                         
    </div>
```

Comment: "правильно ли я сделал?" --- код работает и выполняет всё, что необходимо и задано по заданию?

Comment: там по клику должен удалят, а у меня меняется строка в css, или я что то вопрос не догоняю, вроде бы правильно

Comment: У тебя есть задание, ты написал код. Этот код делает то, что написано в задании или нет?

Comment: правильно но же не текст должен удаляться а класс

Comment: Значит "не правильно"

Comment: помогите плиззз

Comment: Обернул ваш код в сниппет - работает ваша задумка или задачка. Я не вижу каких либо проблем. Классы меняются, текст остается прежним